# When should i use $() in asterisk syntax?

Tags: asterisk

Im very new in asterisk and Im learning all by myself
Im having some warnings in this section... The main problem its the use of () and $$. I dont know when to use and when not.

same => n,Read(angle,${PATH}/shootingangle,2,,1,5)  ;Read from the dialpad 2 digits to angle

same => n,Set(distance=$[2500*SIN((2*${angle})/(180/3.14159))])  ;Calculate distance based on the angle

same => n,ExecIf($[($(distance) <= ${target} + 45)] & $[($(distance) >= ${target} - 45])?Goto(game,7,1) ;and here is where i have the problem...

Comment: No its actually about Asterisk PBX

Answer (score 0):

${something} is variable in asterisk

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-variables/

While () is just grouping for mathematic operations, like in any other techs.

$[]  used for substitution. i.e it evaluate value and put instead. Result should be 1 or 0 for ExecIf.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-cmd-execif/

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-expressions/

ExecIf with GOTO is VERY VERY bad practice, you have GotoIf application.